# DataTables columns().every() : this issue when more than one table

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

DataTables documentation for `columns().every()` https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns().every() :

> This columns().every() method ... sets the context of the callback function to
>   be the column() instance for the column in question.

However, in the code below with two tables, `this` always refers to the first table, even when iterating through columns of the second table. It does not set the class in the second table. Instead, it sets it in the first table twice. What am I doing wrong? Or how can I solve this elegantly?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>DataTables test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.css">
<style>
.bgcolor {
  background-color: red;
}
</style>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead><tr><td>Head
  <tbody><tr><td>Cell in first table
</table>
<table>
  <thead><tr><td>Head
  <tbody><tr><td>Cell in second table
</table>

<script>
$(function() {
  var tables = $('table').DataTable();
  tables.columns().every(function(columnIndex, tableCounter) {
    var nodes = this.nodes();
    $(nodes).addClass('bgcolor');
  });
});
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a3j6zv62/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your selector is just 'table'.

Consider identifying each of your tables and then apply the correct selector:

```
....<table id="example2">....
```

And then:

```
$('#example2').DataTable(.....
```

See the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a3j6zv62/1/

UPDATE:

To do this in all tables of your document just use some jquery looping:

```
$('table').DataTable({dom: 't'});
$('table').each(function() {
  var api = $(this).dataTable().api();
  api.columns().every(function(columnIndex, tableCounter) {
    var nodes = this.nodes();
    console.log([columnIndex, tableCounter, nodes]);    
    $(nodes).addClass('bgcolor');
  });
});
```

See also the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/a3j6zv62/3/

Comment: The Update can do what I am looking for. Thanks. Would the behaviour I noticed be a bug in DataTables?

Comment: about 'just what is should do'. 
I don't understand. every loops through both tables: tableCounter has value 0 and 1, but when it is 1, this refers to the first table instead of the second. Why should it do that? – PaulH 7 m